# Is there any way to style <select> dropdown options container and items?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

Im using contact form 7 on wordpress, i don't want to use a plugin rather use plain css/js to bring the results if possible.

Something like this : [image: Dropdown style]

Comment: The only way to do something like this would be to fake a select dropdown, you can't actually style a `select` dropdown like this because the styling for that element is determined by the browser.

Comment: The select options can't be achieve with CSS alone, the top part can be created with CSS. https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx

Comment: in contact form 7, woocommerce and other forms, I just use jquery to wrap all selects and then I style what I can. Many jQuery plugins won't give you the ability to type in the first few letters of the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browser define select difrent from each other. 
You can use UL and LI to make custom select like list.

Here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2qbhsfrq/), this can help you to make all select look similiar on all browser and on mobile too.

And select would be something like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you give you dropdown an id, then you can select the id using jQuery and use its children method. You can even specify which child.

Something like this:

$("dropdownId").children().css({"color": "yellow", "border": "1px solid red"});

Comment: This would [not have any effect](https://jsfiddle.net/uw3vfwrq/) on the styling of the options.